# Android: "Encoded PCM 16/8-bit" what does it mean?

Tags: android, pcm

"Encoded PCM 16/8-bit" what does it mean?? lets say i have a mp3 music and i want to convert this to a encoded PCM so i could directly feed this to write() of AudioTrack object.

any tools by which i can convert??
and after conversion to PCM will it be playable in android.
(considering i am don't bother about quality)

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

PCM (pulse-code modulation) is a standard encoding scheme used in the WAV file format. It consists of 8- or 16-bit *samples*; there are a number of these per second of audio - that number is called the *sample rate*. `AudioTrack` is used to play back PCM data; this can be done in real-time while you write to its internal buffer (i.e. `MODE_STREAM`), or you can fill the buffer and then play back (`MODE_STATIC`). If you go with the streaming mode, it's important to continuously call `write()` to keep filling the buffer during playback, otherwise the `AudioTrack` will stop playing until it receives more data.

As for tools, a simple one is iTunes. Go to Preferences->General->Import Settings and choose "WAV encoder" from the drop-down menu. Now right-click a file you want to convert and select "Create WAV version". As you mentioned, you will lose a bit of quality, which is inevitable in conversion.

Alternatively to this method, consider using the `MediaPlayer` API, which will play MP3s natively.